# How do I install the Profile2 module?

Tags: users

I am new to Drupal and I have recently installed Drupal 7.15 and downloaded profile2 but I don't know how to install profile2 to Drupal. I came across this [link](http://drupal.org/node/1074296) but I can't find any *profile types* in my Drupal structure. Below is the screen shot of my Drupal struture:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache after install?  Just in case ;-)

Comment: @Chapabu i cleared cache,still its not showing profile types..is it happening only to me or wether its a common thing

Answer (score 2):

1. Inside every Drupal module there is file called README, you must read that to findout how it's should be installed and used.
2. Always clear Drupal's cache just in case : admin/config/development/performance
3. According to README you much visit this link admin/structure/profiles top manage profiles